# Javascript display M3U playlist as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, m3u

How can I display a M3U playlist from a url like this http://siptv.app/lists/example.m3u into text using javascript? Im using phonegap so cors is not an issue

Answer (score 1):

If you try to open m3u file with notepad you will notice that it contains a human-readable text: a list of links. Try to simply parse it as regular text.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ' http://siptv.app/lists/example.m3u',
    success: function(message, text, response) {
        //and then parse
    }
});
```

Comment: yes but how is that done? could you show me an example?

Comment: its showing nothing, what do i put in the parse area to receive the full data?

Comment: @lanjes `console.log()` the variables and pick out the relevant data